# Is there a way to find out if images (assets) are landscape or portrait?

Tags: assets, format, image

In a current project we will list entries in a masonry-style grid view where the entry’s respective cover image should be styled differently based on their image format. Landscape vs. portrait and -- of course -- square.

I haven’t found anything on here or in the docs pointing to a possible way of doing this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about just using the `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` methods available on the [AssetFileModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel)? Something like this:

```
{% set myImage = entry.imagesField.first %}

{% if myImage.getWidth() < myImage.getHeight() %}
  {# portrait #}
{% elseif myImage.getWidth() > myImage.getHeight() %}
  {# landscape #}
{% else %}
  {# square #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Seems like that’s it. Somehow i must have overlooked those. Gonna try this. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)